# Is there any way to set two different svn server to one repository?

Tags: svn

I'm new to source control tools. There's a open source project(actually it's `WebRTC`) which many of our future products will contain. I'm trying to checkout it to our internal SVN server for convenience.

### What I want to do

`WebRTC`(including its third party projects) is updated very quickly. Our internal projects won't keep so close to its pace. But for some important versions of `WebRTC`, I need to update it from `WebRTC`'s remote svn server. I want developers of our future products can update it from our internal SVN server once I update the `WebRTC` repository.

The problem is `WebRTC` is involving two different servers here. What's the ideal solution to this situation.

Thanks,

Peter

Answer (score 1):

**Externals** is what you should [read about](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.advanced.externals.html). Basically they allow you to add external repositories to be checked out whenever a checkout from your repository is done.